# How can I implement Rust's Copy trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to initialise an array of structs in Rust:

```
enum Direction {
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West,
}

struct RoadPoint {
    direction: Direction,
    index: i32,
}

// Initialise the array, but failed.
let data = [RoadPoint { direction: Direction::East, index: 1 }; 4];
```

When I try to compile, the compiler complains that the `Copy` trait is not implemented:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `main::RoadPoint: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:16
   |
15 |     let data = [RoadPoint { direction: Direction::East, index: 1 }; 4]; 
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `main::RoadPoint`
   |
   = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied
```

How can the `Copy` trait be implemented?

Comment: `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` is the right way, but for the record, it's not magical: It's easy to implement those traits manually, especially in easy cases such as yours: `impl Copy for Direction {} impl Clone for Direction { fn clone(&self) -> Self { *self } }`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You don't have to implement [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) yourself; the compiler can derive it for you:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Direction {
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct RoadPoint {
    direction: Direction,
    index: i32,
}
```

Note that every type that implements `Copy` must also implement [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html). `Clone` can also be derived.

Comment: why is the "Clone" needed? Does it always need to be added if one wants to implement Copy?

Comment: @xetra11Yes, `Clone` is a supertrait of `Copy` so every type implementing `Copy` also needs to implement `Clone`.

Comment: It's not exactly an answer, but I rather prefer deriving `Clone` _without_ deriving `Copy`. It allows developers to do `.clone()` on the element explicitly, but it won't do it for you (that's `Copy`'s job). So at least there's a reason for `Clone` to exist separately from `Copy`; I would go further and assume `Clone` implements the method, but `Copy` makes it automatic, without redundancy between the two.

Answer (score 23):

Just prepend `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` before your enum.

If you really want, you can also

```
impl Copy for MyEnum {}
```

The derive-attribute does the same thing under the hood.