# Understanding de-referencing using '*' in rust

Tags: syntax, reference, rust, move-semantics, borrowing

```
struct Abc {
    a: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut abc = Abc { a: 30 };
    let xyz = &abc;
    let q = *xyz;
}
```

Compiling the code gives following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:11:13
   |
11 |     let q = *xyz;
   |             ^^^^
   |             |
   |             cannot move out of borrowed content
   |             help: consider using a reference instead: `&*xyz`
```

Please help me understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158738/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content)

Comment: Can you further describe what is confusing you in this particular example? [This section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) of the book on ownership may help you understand what is happening. Moreover, there are [dozens of other questions with that exact same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+cannot+move+out+of+borrowed+content).

Comment: The below code compiles but whats wrong with the code in question "fn main() {
    
    let mut abc = 10;
    let xyz =  &abc;
    let q = *xyz;
}"

Comment: @user8070445 Numbers are `Copy` types, so they don't get moved. Your struct will be moved when it is assigned to a variable because it is not `Copy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `let a = b;` in Rust, the value of `b` is *moved* to `a`, and the variable `b` is no longer usable.

In your case, `xyz` is a reference to `abc`, so `*xyz` is the same thing as `abc`. Moving `abc` is an error because the reference `xyz` still exists, but now is pointing at invalid memory.

If you are confused why this didn't happen with a numeric type like `i32`, that's because most simple primitives implement the `Copy` trait. This is marker trait which tells the compiler to copy the value in memory, rather than move it. For small types, this can be the same performance as (or sometimes even better than) passing by reference.

See:

- [What are move semantics in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288782/what-are-move-semantics-in-rust)
- [How does Rust provide move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490670/how-does-rust-provide-move-semantics)
- [How can I implement Rust's Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458562/how-can-i-implement-rusts-copy-trait)
- [Documentation of the `Copy` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)
- [Discussion on moving in the ownership chapter of the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ways-variables-and-data-interact-move)